# Excel Lookup/Match exact match only

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup, vlookup

I am a bit confused with lookup/match and the lookup wizard in excel 07 does not seem to allow multiple sheets properly.

What I need is for cell B2:BXXXX on Sheet 2 to run the following and display the answer
compare Cell A2:AXXXX on sheet 2 to the values on D2:D30000 on sheet 3, finding the exact match only
if exact match is found, return the entire contents of Cell L2:L30000 on sheet 3 where the row is the matching row from D2:D30000
If no match is found, return #N/A is fine

example

```
Sheet 2
90336-N 32(formula is here)
90336-R #N/A (formula is copy down'ed this entire column)
```

Sheet 3

```
D   L
90336-N 32
90336   12
90336-Q 8
```

any help? - the entire sheet has alot of financial data as well as company databases that I cannot post, the data above is just simply some "fluff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also want to add `IFERROR()` to the `vlookup` command. This will allow you to search for non-matches more easily and even designate them as something for example:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet3!D$2:L$30000,9,FALSE),"CHECK")
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to use `VLOOKUP`. In B2 on sheet2 use this formula

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet3!D$2:L$30000,9,FALSE)`

You can then copy that formula down the column

The 9 indicates the 9th column of the range Sheet3!D$2:L$30000, because that's the column from which you want to return a value (the match is always done with the first column of that range). VLOOKUP with FALSE as final parameter only returns exact matches or #N/A (although it's not case-sensitive)